# Jenkins execute PowerShell scripts

Tags: windows, powershell, jenkins, jenkins-plugins, executionpolicy

I'm trying to run PowerShell scripts from Jenkins, but it seems to completely ignore the execution policy! This happens either by executing powershell.exe directly, or using the [PowerShell plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/PowerShell+Plugin)

Additional information:

Jenkins is running as a Windows Service (using the Local System account, non-interactive). Connecting to that server, and checking execution policy is indeed `RemoteSigned`:

```
PS C:\> whoami
nt authority\system

PS C:\> Get-ExecutionPolicy
RemoteSigned
PS C:\>
```

However, when running a Jenkins build, this is not the case. Here's the output of executing `Get-ExecutionPolicy -List` inside a build step:

```
d:\workspace\test-job>powershell Get-ExecutionPolicy -list 
  Scope                         ExecutionPolicy
  -----                         ---------------
  MachinePolicy                 Undefined
  UserPolicy                    Undefined
  Process                       Undefined
  CurrentUser                   Undefined
  LocalMachine                  Undefined
```

I also tried setting it explicitly from the build step, nothing.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

After more than two hours of pulling my hair, the problem was x86/x64!!!

Turns out, `Set-ExecutionPolicy` of x64 (default) PowerShell has no effect on the x86 settings!

Jenkins is a 32-bit process, running from a Windows service - it executes the x86 PowerShell!

In addition, the Modules directory for x86 PowerShell is located under `%systemroot%\SysWow64\WindowsPowerShell\1.0\Modules`, another important fact to remember!

Comment: Your answer also tipped me off to the fact that I needed to set separate Registry values for x86 processes.