# Jenkins with Sharepoint Solution Deployer

Tags: powershell, sharepoint, jenkins, sharepoint-2010

I can't seem to figure out why if I run the script in Jenkins (local machine), then I get the

> The Windows PowerShell snap-in 'Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell' is not installed on this machine.

But if I run it outside Jenkins (i.e., running powershell from start menu), then it's fine. I looked at the GAC and the .dll is there.

Comment: This could be a stupid question, but have you installed the [Jenkins Powershell Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/PowerShell+Plugin)?

Comment: There's no stupid question. Yes, I did. :)

Comment: What happens if you run 32-bit PowerShell (the x86 version) from the Start menu?  Just a thought, since Jenkins apparently runs the 32-bit version (see http://stackoverflow.com/a/24531714/1001100)

Comment: @JamesQMurphy Yup, I figured it was running on 32-bit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution I found is that since Jenkins runs 32-bit. I had to install JRE 64bit and point jenkins to run at 64bit so the powershell will run at 64-bit.

**Using SharePoint for PowerShell always has to be 64-bit.**